# Creating a custom audio player with jPlayer

Tags: jquery, audio, media-player, html5-audio, jplayer

Following [this](http://www.karolodesign.com/blog/developer/177-jplayer-how-to-use-jplayer-to-build-your-own-mp3-player.html) article, I'm trying to create a simple custom audio player using [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/).

This is the HTML code

```
<div id="audio-player">
    <div id="track-info">

    </div>
    <div id="player-buttons">
        <div id="player">
            <div id="playButton" class="button">
                <img id="play-button" src="images/bage-playing.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="pauseButton" class="button">
                <img id="pause-button" src="images/bage-paused.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="stopButton" class="button">
                <img id="stop-button" src="images/bage-busy.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- end of audio-player -->
```

And it looks like this.

[image]

I put the following script in a separate JS file and added it in the HTML page's head along with the jPlayer's JS file.

My problem is when I run the page, the buttons disappear! I'm completely clueless what's causing this.

If anybody has encountered a similar situation before or if you have any suggestion to get this working, I'm all ears.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to say for certain what is happening here without an example URL, but a couple of things to bear in mind:

When using JPlayer, once you have 'bound' the controls using the 'cssSelectors' property of the API, it will manipulate these controls itself using Javascript DOM methods, and by applying inline CSS to DOM items.

Firstly, it's worth knowing that JPlayer will hide the Play and Pause buttons one at a time when appropriate.  E.g. When the track is playing, it will hide the play button, and when the track is paused, it will hide the play button - this could be the cause of some of your issues.

More likely the issue is that you have div containers for the buttons, and are specifiying them, and jPlayer is then clearing their contents.  If you change from having images within your button divs, and use backgrounds and specified sizes on the divs, I suspect your code will work.

Your code looks like this:

```
<div id="audio-player">
    <div id="track-info">

    </div>
    <div id="player-buttons">
        <div id="player">
            <div id="playButton" class="button">
                <img id="play-button" src="images/bage-playing.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="pauseButton" class="button">
                <img id="pause-button" src="images/bage-paused.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="stopButton" class="button">
                <img id="stop-button" src="images/bage-busy.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd change it to:

```
<div id="audio-player">
    <div id="track-info">

    </div>
    <div id="player-buttons">
        <div id="player">
            <div id="playButton" class="button">
            </div>
            <div id="pauseButton" class="button">
            </div>
            <div id="stopButton" class="button">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then add some css like this to restore the images:

```
#playButton {
    background: transparent url('images/bage-playing.png') no-repeat;
    height: 20px; /* Correct this size ;-) */
    width: 20px; /* Also correct this size ;-) */
}
```

Then do the same for each button, and I expect that your code will work.  If it doesn't, post back with a URL to a demo of what you're doing, and I'll take a better look.

Owen

**ADDENDUM:**

Now you've posted your code, I can see two issues that will hopefully make it work when you fix them:

Firstly, you're selecting elements not IDs in your javascript.  Where you have the 'cssSelector' object, the strings you are using say:

```
cssSelector: { 
        play: 'playButton',
        pause: 'pauseButton',
        stop: 'stopButton'
    },
```

When they should say:

```
cssSelector: { 
    play: '#playButton',
    pause: '#pauseButton',
    stop: '#stopButton'
},
```

Your version would select elements by name, not ID, e.g.  not .  I'm guessing this is because you're used to using document.getElementById, or maybe mooTools.

As well as this, your 'ready' call within the JPlayer setup is missing a function.  It looks like this:

```
ready: jQuery(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { 
                mp3: 'http://www.karolodesign.com/media/music/bass-walker.mp3'
            });
```

and should look like this:

```
ready: function() { // This bit!
            jQuery(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { 
                mp3: 'http://www.karolodesign.com/media/music/bass-walker.mp3'
            });
       }
```

Which is my fault, as my original example on the website actually has it wrong!  I'll correct that straightaway.

Fix those two issues, and it should be ok.  JQuery is throwing an error, but I think that's just because of the lack of a function.  Let me know if it doesn't work, and I'll take another look.

Owen

Comment: First of all, thanks a ton for getting back to me fast! I changed the HTML like you instructed and added the images through the CSS but to no avail. I have uploaded everything to [here](http://kode.co.nf/)

Comment: See addition to my answer, I hope it'll save your problems.

Comment: Thank you for pointing those mistakes out, Owen. I updated my code but still the player is not appearing on the page at all! I've uploaded all my files [here](http://www17.zippyshare.com/v/8138167/file.html). I thought it would be easier for you to see the code and everything as it is. Please download it and take a look. Thanks again. :)